# Unable to locate element -- OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, specflow, gherkin

I am trying to automate a test case through Specflow, by using the Gherkin format, but I keep getting the error:

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./ancestor-or-self::form"}

The button that cannot be located is commented in the AddCart Page below.

The website that I am testing is: http://automationpractice.com/index.php

What I am trying to achieve is as seen below:

```
Feature: Adding products in the cart

  Scenario Outline: Adding a product of the HomePage in the cart and continue shopping
    Given That the user is on the HomePage
    When User clicks the Add to cart button
    And User clicks the Continue shopping button
    Then The user will stay on the HomePage
```

The code of the Step Definition is:

```
namespace WebsiteTestingSpecflow.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class AddingCartContinueStep
    {

        AddCartPage addcart = null;

        [Given(@"That the user is on the HomePage")]
        public void GivenThatTheUserIsOnTheHomePage()
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
            addcart = new AddCartPage(webDriver);
        }

        [When(@"User clicks the Add to cart button")]
        public void WhenUserClicksTheAddToCartButton()
        {
            addcart.AddCart();
        }

        [When(@"User clicks the Continue shopping button")]
        public void WhenUserClicksTheContinueShoppingButton()
        {
            addcart.ContinueShopping();
        }

        [Then(@"The user will stay on the HomePage")]
        public void ThenTheUserWillStayOnTheHomePage()
        {
            addcart.Verifyelement();
        }

    }
}
```

The code of the AddCart Page is:

```
namespace WebsiteTestingSpecflow.Pages
{
    public class AddCartPage
    {

        private readonly WebDriverWait wait;

        public IWebDriver Webdriver { get; }

        public AddCartPage(IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            Webdriver = webDriver;
            wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

        public IWebElement BtnAddCart => Webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#homefeatured > .ajax_block_product:nth-child(1) .button:nth-child(1) > span"));
 // This is the button that I keep getting error. 

        public IWebElement btnContinueCart => Webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".continue > span"));


         public void AddCart() {
            BtnAddCart.Submit(); 
        
        }

        public void ContinueShopping() {

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".continue > span")));
            btnContinueCart.Submit();
        
        }

        public void Verifyelement() => Webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".sfHover > .sf-with-ul"));
    }
}
```

The CSS Selector of that button is as mentioned in the AddCart Page, but it still unable to locate the element.

May anyone know how can I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to find element at the moment when it's not visible yet, because  it will be visible only when you click to Add to cart and only then that element can be reached.
Try code below and also consider using Page Object model

```
        public void ContinueShopping() {

        IWebElement btnContinueCart => Webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".continue > span"));               
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(".continue > span")));
        btnContinueCart.Submit();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, the problem is not on the Continue button, but rather on the first button that needs to be pressed, which is Add to cart. That is the element that the program cannot read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to incorporate [Actions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) into your code since this button is not visible unless you hover over it.  Also add a `wait` condition around it

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    var btn = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("#homefeatured > .ajax_block_product:nth-child(1) .button:nth-child(1) > span")));
    action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#homefeatured > .ajax_block_product:nth-child(1) .button:nth-child(1) > span"))).Build().Perform();
    btn.Click();
```

Add the following to the top:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

[image]